# I need a MutableStateMap capable of retaining order such as LinkedHashMap

Tags: android, hashmap, state, android-jetpack-compose

A `SnapshotStateMap` is great for working with key-value pairs in Compose as it allows you to track changes to said pairs without reassigning the entire map. However, State mostly being used to affect the UI, it would be great to have a way to have it retain a certain order, just like a `LinkedHashMap`.
Is there an elegant way to achieve this or am I forced to add an additional `List` of the keys that reflects the order in which I want the values to be shown?

Comment: I provide you a solution below, we can check together

Comment: @Sachin nothing yet, maybe they ll add it in the future. Until then we I found that redundantly storing the keys inside the values of the stateMap helps in sorting the map by some value while also retaining the ability to update a single element  in the map